# python not finding _ldap

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-ldap

What I'm looking to do is install and use python on a python install that isn't the system default.

It's a 64-bit Python.NET install, version 2.7.11.

I've installed pip, and the latest 64-bit wheel for python-ldap. I could not use the version available on PyPl as it is only 32-bit.

To test if I can import ldap I run:
    dpython.exe -c "import ldap"

Which returns:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Program Files\Thinkbox\Deadline8\bin\lib\site-packages\ldap\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import _ldap
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Checking pip for what I thinks is installed:

```
pip list
```

Returns:

```
pip (8.1.2)
python-ldap (2.4.25)
setuptools (24.3.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

What's really strange is that I've successfully installed and used this exact same wheel on my system's python install (the one located in C:\Python27).

What am I missing to get python to find this module?

Comment: Do you have a file called ldap.py in your main project

Comment: Here is the thing, you could try to print your sys.path at each of your python instance, the pip might just install the ldap to one of your folders, and if you are capable to import ldap, type ldap.__file__, generally it's at your python/lib/site-package, things would be much clear if you check these one by one

Comment: @idjaw I don't have a file named ldap.py in my project.

Comment: @JackWu I've printed my sys.path, and the lib\site-packages folder is on the path.

I'm not able to import ldap at all, so I cannot test ldap.__file__.

Comment: are you capable to run python at cmd, both python and pip should be in PATH

Comment: @JackWu Sorry for the delayed answer, both python and pip are in the path.

Comment: @Justin B, wher you able to get a resolution for the problem? I 've run into the exact issue and looking for a resolution.